# Not able to create organisation repository using a fine grained token

Tags: git, github, github-api

I have created a fine grained token and set the organisation as owner of the token, also included the Repositories: Administration permission to the token. After getting approval from the organisation owner for using token I ran the github API `gh api --method POST /orgs/${org_name}/repos -f name='Hello-World'` to create a repository but getting the below error

```
{
gh: You need admin access to the organization before adding a repository to it. (HTTP 403)
  "message": "You need admin access to the organization before adding a repository to it.",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/repos/repos#create-an-organization-repository"
}
```

Have I missed any extra permissions to add?

Comment: What's the output of `gh auth status`? Does it show the token or your individual account?

Comment: it shows the pat token

Comment: Are you able to create repos with `gh repo create`?

Comment: yeah I am able to create using `gh repo create`

Comment: why is it not working with the `gh api` command? I also tried with `pygithub` (python library for github) and was unable to create the repo